# Create video from List of images using Xuggler

Tags: java, image, xuggler

For a school project I am busy with a program that will alow you to create and edit a stopmotion video. My question to you is: How do I create a video from a list of images? I've heard that xuggler works pretty well, but I can't find any way to do it. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: the lessons your teacher gave you can : )

Comment: Haha our teachers don't teach us things like this :s We have to figure it out ourselfs ;)